# Are Push Notifications currently broken for the Stack Exchange iOS App?

Tags: support, bug, ios-app, notifications

I've just downloaded the latest build of the Stack Exchange app from the App Store, and despite both enabling notifications and logging into my account am not receiving notifications - as an example, when an answer to one of my questions is submitted or a new comment added. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Generally, logging out of the app, killing it, and logging back in fixes this issue. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: I use SE iOS app extensively. Push notifications have been working fine for me.